Random 404 errors on page load using Vercel and Nextjs 14
I need help with my projects that keep getting random 404 errors.
I am running a project build with nextjs 14, that is connected with 100+ domains.
When visiting the individual sites, i receive at random times 404 responses. When reloading the sites, everything loads.
Here are some logs that i get:


This is my next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: 'localhost',
            },
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: '**.cloudfront.net',
            },
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: '**.cloudfront.net',
            },
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: '**.cloudfront.net',
            },
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
            },
        ],
    },
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'static/fonts/[name][ext]',
            },
        });
        return config;
    },
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/media/:path*',
                destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_BASE_URL}/:path*`,
            },
        ];
    },
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/leave-a-review',
                destination: 'https://reviews.***.com',
                permanent: false,
                basePath: false,
            },
        ];
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
    module.exports,
    {
        silent: true,
        org: '***',
        project: '***',
    },
    {
        widenClientFileUpload: true,
        transpileClientSDK: true,
        hideSourceMaps: true,
        disableLogger: true,
        automaticVercelMonitors: true,
    },
);

